# Form error messages are not displaying in colorbox

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, status-messages

I have a custom form which is displaying in a colorbox.

But the problem is when I set an error in validate function using `form_set_error`, the red border appears against the field but the error message is not displaying.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code too?

Comment: Is it ajax form?

Comment: No its not an ajax form.